# GhostScript PDF Compression - PDF Size Increasing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to compress the PDF file using my Asp.Net application with GhostScript.  But somehow i couldn't get the successful ouput for some PDF.

**GhostScript Application Details**

Version : 9.19

name : gswin64c.exe

**Please have a look at the below mentioned issue.**

My issue is, for some PDF, ghost compression technique is not working fine rather it increases the File size.

For eg. please have a look at this [link](https://drive.google.com/a/tradingbell.com/folderview?id=0B6dwJntQAxG_cFVpVEdsbFBnSXc&usp=sharing#)  (Here i have added some of input and output files, which i had tested with application)

**Case 1: PDF compression not worked as desired.**

Here B_BeforeCompression.pdf (its size is 369 KB) is the source PDF, when i compress it using the GhostPDF Compression technique it actually increases its size B_AfterCompression.pdf (its size is 473 KB)

**Case 2: PDF Compression worked fine**

Here A_BeforeCompression.pdf (its size is 1458 KB) when it  is compressed, the output PDF is generated as A_AfterCompression.pdf size is 286 KB.

Here my question is, Why this contrary occurs (a technique works with one PDF but not successfully do with the another PDF.)

```
 "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="OutputPDF" "InputPDF";
```

Please give me the possible solution that would make the PDF Compression is compatible for the all the PDF files.

Comment: What makes you believe that the pdfwrite gs device actually does any "compression"? If the input file already is "compressed" in the sense gs would, how should it get any smaller? You don't say if it's about bitmap images in the pdf like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544) - compression depends on the content as described in one of the comments there

Comment: @StefanHegny Thanks for your reply...Case no:2 Made me believe that the above mentioned code can compress the PDF file.

Answer (score 3):

Ghostscript does not, ever, *compress* a PDF file. see the Overview in this [document](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.19/VectorDevices.htm)

What the Ghostscript pdfwrite device does is produce a **new** PDF, the goal of this device is that the visual appearance of the PDF file should be the same as the appearnace of the input, no matter what format the input was in (originally PostScript it now works, with differing degrees of success, with PostScript, PDF, PCL, PXL and XPS input).

The way the PDF interpreter and the pdfwrite device work, it may be that the new file is smaller than the original, particularly if you use aggressive processing on the input such as downsampling the resolution of any images. However, this is by no means guaranteed, as you have discovered.

There is, therefore, no "solution that would make the PDF Compression is compatible for the all the PDF files."

Comment: thank you so much for your time and Clear explanation.  Could you suggest any other tool which could do PDF compression at the reasonable success rate.

Comment: Nope, no clues. Why do you think it should even be possible to 'compress' a PDF file anyway ? Any file which can be compressed (without losing information) was poorly constructed in the first place, I would consider getting new PDF creation software in this case.

Comment: The reason that the file is larger after running through Ghostscript is because the original file does not contain the fonts it requires. When processing this input, Ghostscript will find substitute fonts to use in place of the missing fonts, and the output contains those substitute fonts embedded in the PDF file. Since the output file is only 3kB larger than the input, and contains all the fonts, its pretty clear that it *is* 'compressed'. Of course, the appearance is now incorrect, but that's what happens when you sue fonts and don't embed them.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable information.  I really appreciate for your time. The reason that i am looking for compression technique is, I generate dynamic PDF which comprises more than 250 page. In an attempt to reduce the PDF rendering time, i thought compressing the PDF may have positive impact . However i check with your suggestion to proceed further.

Comment: Compressing the PDF would make it slower to render, since decompressing a compressed stream and then interpreting and rendering will obviously take longer then simply interpreting and rendering. In order to decrease rendering time you would need to analyse the files and see which content is taking time to render. Likely culprits include transparency (most likely and a huge consumer of resources), shading patterns and calibrated colour. You can disable transparency with Ghostscript, but obviously the output will not be correct (unless the file contains 'spurious' transparency).